# Symfony date widgets customizations

Tags: symfony, date, widget, customization

I am new to Symfony and I just discovered the date widget, `->add('dueDate', 'date', array('widget' => 'single_text'))`, delivering the following output:
[image]

**I wonder if it's possible to customize the widget output so that only dates and years I have in my database are selectable in the widget?**

I want only dates and years fetched from my database entries to be selectable options in the date widget with the rest greyed out.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 2):

I might be wrong, but I think this (on picture) is a built-in `Chrome`'s datapicker (which utilizes `date` input type). Furhtermore, majority of browsers **do not have** their own built-in datepickers (e.g. latest `Firefox`)

You might be able to find a way to style it (very limited, presumably), but to fine grain the selection, it would take for you to use some `JS`-based solution.

Something like this?

- https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: It seems you are right. I tried the same page in FireFox and the date picker just shows as an empty textfield. Not sure how to proceed. The datepicker needs to be available to all browsers

Comment: yes, you are right, this is chrome datepicker, which works only in chrome. It appeared because input type is date.

Comment: @sisko Use [DateTimepickerBundle](https://github.com/stephanecollot/DatetimepickerBundle)

Comment: @xurshid29: OP didn't specify he was using Bootstrap :)

Answer (score 1):

If would suggest you to disable `html5` datepicker and use `jquery` version.

Disable html5 and attach jquery:

```
$builder->add('date_created', 'date', array(
    'widget' => 'single_text',
    'html5'  => false,
    'format' => 'd/MM/y',
    'attr' => array(
        'class' => 'datetimepicker'
    )
));
```

datepicker configuration:

```
$('.datetimepicker').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the date type outputs this in html:

```
<input type="date" name=... >
```

Which is a valid HTML5 input type. With this type all major browsers will show you some kind of calendar but this is browser-depended!

You can consider a javascript solution like jqueries datepicker or the [datetimepicker that i like](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) but in that case you should use just a normal text field (->add('dueDate', 'text');) and follow the conventions of the date(time)picker of your choice at clientside.

Comment: Using a simple textfield will be challenging. The scenario is that there are date entries in a database which are related to log entries. So I was thinking of providing a date picker which has selectable dates where they exist in the database. A textfield is just inviting people to make mistakes which I want to avoid because this will also serve as a mobile site

Comment: All data that your server (php script) accepts from the outside world should be validated as much as possible. A datepicker works client-side so the data is not safe. What i try to explain is that you can make a user friendly solution client-side (with html and javascript) and that you validate the posted data server-side which you should always do. If you want to prevent users to enter the input into the textfields then you could make it readonly or even hidden.